# United States B-2 Visa for Indonesian with Australian Permanent Residency

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas

Likelihood of an Indonesian man, (married to Australian woman) permanent residency in Australia, obtaining a B-2 visa to travel to US for 3 weeks for a holiday with Australian wife's family.
Is it straightforward with interview/application.
Thank you

Comment: Whether or not you'll get a visa depends on your detailed circumstances. And even if we knew all the details, anything we said would just be speculation.

Comment: Just to throw some statistics out there, the visa refusal rate per the [USA Government](https://travel.state.gov/content/dam/visas/Statistics/Non-Immigrant-Statistics/RefusalRates/FY17.pdf) for Indonesians is 11% (surprisingly low) and that for Australians is 17%. These are averages just to give you an idea. Nobody can tell you what will happen to you however if you prepare a good application without any hidden issues we do not know about, your chances are very good.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This sounds reasonably straightforward on the face of it, because of his PR in Australia, although there are never any guarentees.

Nobody can give you a percentage because it depends very highly on individual factors (finances, employment, past travel history in the US etc.)